# Wordpress timezone is wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone, schedule

I have this kind of issue and I hope that somebody can help me. 
First of all if I want to publish a POST or PAGE, my content is scheduled and the post is published 1 hour later. If I want to change the hour, I **[Edit the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7Fj.png)** and I see this.
I think this issue is due to UTC time. I already checked everyhing.
I installed a plugin called **Scheduled Post Trigger** but is not solving my problem.

After that I checked the hour setted in Wordpress and [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjArz.png)

My [php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jqWT.png) it's ok and the [time of server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALcv1.png) also.

This is how it looks in [my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXWeD.png) and this is how it looks in the [remote server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnvjW.png)

Comment: it's looks like you have a problem in the server configuration. if your are in Spain, the time zone should be UTC+1 and not UTC.

Comment: Yes that's true. But it seems that the everything about the hour is setted well. But in Wordpress settings, the UTC hour is showed as local and not as trully UTC

Comment: What details can you tell us about your server environment?  Which OS, versions of WordPress and PHP, etc.  Likely there is something wrong there that can be resolved.  Also, where possible please post text, not pictures of the code. Read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center for further suggestions.

Comment: Also, you might consider asking on [WordPress.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) instead, as it appears the problem is possibly related to WordPress server configuration.